# Существует ли массив... матов?

Tags: база-данных

Пишу авторизацию в приложении и хочется отсечь попытки неадекватных школьников уже на этом этапе вписать в `EditText` невалидное имя (маты).

Проверку хотел сделать через `.contains` `ArrayList<String>`, дак вот после наверное двадцатого элемента фантазия кончилась :) да и не совсем по душе пришлось занятие :)

Поэтому вопрос - может кто уже делал подобную *БД* и может поделиться (на полный список не рассчитываю по понятным причинам), чтобы просто Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.

PS. Просьба отнестись с пониманием и не пинать больно - с подобной задачей столкнулся впервые.

Comment: не думаю, что этот вопрос относится к Андроид.     
Вот что удалось найти мне:    
http://www.bannedwordlist.com/lists/swearWords.xml    
Думаю, можно еще поизвращаться с запросом в гугл, и найти что ни будь подобное на русском    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20dirty%20words%20list&es_th=1

Comment: Спасибо за корректировку. Да, список нужен именно в кириллице.

Comment: Вот мой списочек https://club.panasonic.ru/stopwords.txt

Comment: Вы не сможете адекватно детектировать мат без настоящего, живого модератора. Любой школьник быстро догадается заменять русскую `у` на английский `y` или переставить две буквы без особой потери смысла. Кроме того, что делать с частями слов («оскор**блять**»)? Разрешать их тотально или запрещать?

Comment: Попробуйте распарсить список запрещенных доменов .рф там неплохой список мата составили http://vnovokubanske.ru/internet1/262-zapret-domen-rf.html

Comment: Вспоминаю один форум, который старательно замарывал слово "троебуквие". Меня это жутко бесило. Я долго не мог понять, что там вообще могло почудиться. Это надо иметь очень больную фантазию...

Comment: В данном случае таблица подобных слов может оказаться полезной, но в дополнение к модерации системы. Фантазия пользователя может оказаться более изощренной чем подразумевает ваш список

Comment: Я думаю следует разработать систему, где можно кликнув на слово пометить её как матное, и после премодерации скрывать её от глаз людей (заменять на звёздочки например). Премодерировать легко - результат должен быть превосходным :) Ну естественно основные матные слова нужно будет добавить ручками.

Comment: [Хабрахабр - Пишем фильтр «плохих» слов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/101232/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Тема стара как мир.*

Из того, что я видел, именно [php-censure](https://github.com/rin-nas/php-censure) - скрипт на PHP для определения нецензурных слов - оказался лучше других по отзывам. Можете взять на вооружение подход, который в нём используется: "плохие" слова определяются по частям. Отдельно приставка, отдельно корень и тд. Именно потому, что матерных слов существует не много, а много - производных от них, такой подход работает хорошо. Также используется список "хороших" слов, чтобы не зацензурировать лишнего.

- А вот на форуме Vingrad [выложили архив](http://forum.vingrad.ru/index.php?showtopic=320533&view=findpost&p=2285953) из ~200 матерных выражений (нужна учётная запись на сайте для скачивания).
- [Список](http://code.google.com/p/zlo-search/source/browse/trunk/zlo_search/src/main/java/info/xonix/zlo/search/utils/obscene/obscene.txt), используемый в zlo-search.
- [Список нецензурных слов](http://spisok.lt/spisok-netsenzurnyih-slov-russkiy-yazyik/) и производных.
- [Список нецензурных слов](http://www.myadept.ru/index.php/page/spisok-necenzurnyh-slov-dlja-anti-spama-i-cenzury) для анти-спама и цензуры.